# Looking for a citation for a result of Littlewood

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function

I see that it is proven by Hardy in 1914 that there are an infinite number of zeros on the critical line.  I also see that the Hardy and Littlewood conjectures appear in some papers they wrote together in 1921.  However, it was further proven by Littlewood alone that if $\gamma_n$ is an increasing sequence of the imaginary parts of the zeros on the critical line in the upper complex half-plane then

$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|\gamma_n-\gamma_{n-1}| =0 ~~.$$

Can someone please give me the citation for the paper in which Littlewood proved this result on his own?  I absolutely cannot find it!

Comment: Look in Titchmarsh's book where a proof is given, and you'll also find a reference to Littlewood's paper.

Comment: Thanks!  Could you send me a link to the PDF of that book with the page number?

Comment: Two notes on the Riemann zeta-function, Proc. Camb. Phil. Soc. 22 (1924), 234-242. https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100014158